# Why LEFT is always traversed before RIGHT in PreOrder, InOrder & PostOrder of Tree Traversal

Tags: java, c, algorithm, data-structures, tree

The total traversal combinations, possible for the below mentioned *Sample Tree* are

```
DLR, LDR, LRD, DRL, RDL, RLD
```

Sample Tree [ D=root , L= LeftNode , R= RightNode ]

```
  D
 / \
L   R
```

PreOrder:  DLR

InOrder:   LDR

PostOrder: LRD

Why other combinations like ***DRL, RDL & RLD*** never considered ?

Comment: I think that is just the way it's defined depending upon the usability use cases.

Answer (score 0):

In a binary tree, the first child is on the left and the second child is on the right. In the combinations, **DRL, RDL, and RLD**, `R` comes before `L` which is against the concept of Tree and therefore they are never considered for the traversal of a binary tree.

Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) to learn more about the Tree data structure.

Comment: I read the link you mentioned.. it appears.. the first child & second child reference which they have used, is for explaining how to draw a tree on paper!

Comment: Example: Imagine a Right Skew Tree of size 2 (we should not be referring to its child as second child)